# PHP 8 Method overriding with different types from the same BaseClass

Tags: php, php-8

My project is running fine on PHP 7.X and after upgrading to PHP 8 I have the following problem and I don't know how to fix this.

I have a the following (simplified) situation:

```
<?php

class Vehicle
{
    //...
}

class Car extends Vehicle
{
    //...
}


class VehicleOutputMaker
{
    public function output(Vehicle $entity)
    {
        
    }
}


class CarOutputMaker extends VehicleOutputMaker
{
    //THROWS EXCEPTION
    public function output(Car $entity)
    {
        parent::output($entity);
    }
}
```

My whole project is running like this but since PHP 8 I get an exception for the line

`public function output(Car $entity)`

with "FATAL ERROR: Declaration of *** must be compatible with ***"

It worked perfectly well with PHP 7! Because "Car" is also a Vehicle.

Somebody has an idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: It did not _work perfectly well with PHP 7_, the only difference was you got a `Warning` in stead of a `Fatal error`. Read up on how inheritance works [`inheritance`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php).

Comment: Yes thanks, it was indeed a warning in PHP 7 and now it's a fatal error. But I can't understand why they made it so strict now. A `Car` is a `Vehicle` und when I change the type hint from `Car` to `Vehicle` it works, yes. But I still can pass `Car` objects to the method although the type is `Vehicle` and `declare(strict_types = 1)` was set. I would expect the get a fatal error when passing a `Car` object to a method which expects `Vehicle` but... it works. And my declaration above says just the same but won't get accepted by PHP 8...

Comment: "But I still can pass Car objects to the method although the type is Vehicle"...yes, obviously, because a Car is a type of Vehicle. That's the whole point of inheritance.

Comment: But basically the issue is it's illogical to override a method using a different signature than it has in the parent class. You can't do that in other strongly-typed OO languages, either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you got a warning and now a fatal error is due to the fact that your code doesn't respect the [Liskov substitution principle (LSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) standard requirement of [contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) of method parameter types in the subtype.

With this in mind, the issue is that while a method in a sub-class can expand the range of parameter types, it must accept all parameter types that the parent class accepts.

Your sub-class `CarOutputMaker` breaks this rule, its method `output()` accepts a parameter of type `Car` (a sub-type of `Vehicle`), but not a parameter of super-type `Vehicle` as declared in its parent method `VehicleOutputMaker::output()`.

So this would be valid in PHP7:

```
class VehicleOutputMaker  
{  
    public function output(Vehicle $entity)  
    {  
    }  
}  
  
class CarOutputMaker extends VehicleOutputMaker  
{  
    public function output(Vehicle $entity)  
    {  
        parent::output($entity);  
    }  
}
```

Noteworthy, since you're using PHP8, you can use [union types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php#language.types.declarations.union) to type-hint both types in your sub-class: `Vehicle|Car`.

```
class VehicleOutputMaker  
{  
    public function output(Vehicle $entity)  
    {  
    }  
}  
  
class CarOutputMaker extends VehicleOutputMaker  
{  
    public function output(Vehicle|Car $entity)  
    {  
        parent::output($entity);  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not change the type hint of Car to Vehicle, since then the parent class' method signature is respected.

You would then have to type check and cast the Vehicle type to Car inside the CarOutputMaker's output method if you would want to execute Car specific behaviour.

```
class CarOutputMaker extends VehicleOutputMaker
{
    //THROWS EXCEPTION
    public function output(Vehicle $entity)
    {
        parent::output($entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is possible, but I know that this method will always called with `Car` and not `Vehicle`. But I will need to rewrite it when I want to support PHP 8. Seems that there is no way to just declare a flag and go on working..